# How to determine which endpoint initiated a connection when using GetActiveTcpConnections() in C#

Tags: c#

This code works fine, however I would like to know if it's possible to get the information on who initiated each connection? Like in which endpoint initiated the connection. Is that possible?

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public static void ShowActiveTcpConnections()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Active TCP Connections");
    IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
    foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}",
                          c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(),
                          c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP Connections are received on listing ports.  Connections made inbound would be returned from GetActiveTcpListeners(), and could be deducted from GetActiveTcpConnections() to get the connections made outbound.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcplisteners(v=vs.110).aspx

You might take a look at http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

This will tell you how to get the process:

Console.WriteLine("  {0}", processModule.FileName);

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robert. However I do believe you're wrong, GetActiveTcpConnections() return both inbound and outbound connections.

Comment: If the connection came from getActiveListeners() then you know it was inbound.  I will edit the answer

Comment: Okay than plan sounds alot better, I will try it out :-)